# logstash example plugin not working

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm just starting with Logstash. I've been able to run it using built-in plugins such as `ruby-debug` and `csv`. I'm trying now to create a custom plugin and had issues following the tutorial [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/_how_to_write_a_logstash_output_plugin.html)

I got up to the step of installing the plugin. My plugin was located at $LS_HOME/plugins/logstash-output-example/ so, from $LS_HOME, I ran

```
bin/plugin install plugins/logstash-output-example/logstash-output-example-0.1.3.gem
```

which gave me this output

```
Validating plugins/logstash-output-example/logstash-output-example-0.1.3.gem
Installing logstash-output-example
Installation successful
```

I was pretty satisfied. To test I ran

```
bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin {} } output { example{} }';
```

which gave me

```
The error reported is: 
Couldn't find any output plugin named 'example'. Are you sure this is correct? 
Trying to load the example output plugin resulted in this error: no such file to load -- logstash/outputs/example
```

Then I was sad. What did I do wrong?

For reference, here's the plugin code

```
# encoding: utf-8
require "logstash/outputs/base"
require "logstash/namespace"

# An example output that does nothing.
class LogStash::Outputs::Example < LogStash::Outputs::Base
  config_name "example"

  public
  def register
  end # def register

  public
  def receive(event)
    return "Event received"
  end # def event
end # class LogStash::Outputs::Example
```

Answer (score 0):

you should see in your Gemfile , if your plugin example is there , else your plugin didnot installed correctly !

Comment: I checked and saw an entry for it all the way at the bottom. it was saved in vendor/local_gems/{some hash string}/logstash-filter-myfilter. But when I went to that directory, there was nothing there. Instead, my (albeit hacky) solution was to manually copy the plugin to whatever directory the Gemfile pointed to. That seemed to work. But I'm interested in what the correct procedure should be.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Is it some issue with the building the gem?

Comment: I tried manually copying the gem into the directory as Bob did, but while it does list the new plugin when I type "plugin list", I also get an error message reading "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

Now, I am using a mirror repository for rubygems because I'm working in an isolated system with no access to the external web.